# Get AD Group User's email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

How we can retrieve the email id of the user who has belonged to a particular group. I have one application in which i need to send the email to a Security group from sharepoint. I got the list of users by using this code.

```
PrincipalContext principal = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principal,  picker.DisplayText);
var members = groupPrincipal.GetMembers(true);
```

the members variable should returns the group users, So i need to pick each of the user's email id from this collection. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Wait, just re-read the question and want to verify.  You want to send email to a Security group that should be a member of the group you found above?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this.  Here are two simple options with few lines of code.

If your UPNs match your email addresses you *could* do something like this:

```
var userEmails = new List<string>();
foreach (var member in members)
{
    userEmails.Add(member.UserPrincipalName);
}
```

If that is not stringent enough and you want to actually pull the email the easiest way is probably to pull the user principal and read it's email property.

```
foreach (var member in members)
{
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, member.SamAccountName);
    userEmails.Add(user.EmailAddress);
}
```

If you don't like those options you could pull a DirectoryEntry or read the attribute directly but other than speed I wouldn't go those routes.

Also, please add appropriate error handling etc.